# What vector bundles are tangent bundles of smooth manifolds?

Tags: category-theory, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles, grassmannian, tangent-bundle

Given a smooth manifold $M$, we can naturally associate to it a vector bundle ${\rm T}M\rightarrow M$ called the *tangent bundle* of $M$. This operation induces a functor $\rm T:\rm Diff\rightarrow\rm Vect(Diff)$ from the category of smooth manifolds to the category of real vector bundles over smooth manifolds.

Is it possible to give a precise meaning for the question 'what vector bundles are tangent bundles' by asking: what is the image of the functor $\rm T$ in the category $\rm Vect(Diff)$ ? Put this way, is there a standard answer for that question?

On the other hand, let ${\rm Gr}(k,V)$ denote the Grassmannian of $k$-dimensional subspaces of a $n$-dimensional vector space $V$. Then it is known (is it, indeed? I am still in the process of absorbing these matters, so any corrections shall be really appreciated, terminology included!) that for any real vector bundle $\pi:E\rightarrow M$ over a (compact?) smooth manifold $M$, there are $k,n\in\Bbb N$ and a smooth map $\mu:M\rightarrow{\rm Gr}(k,V)$, such that the bundle $\pi$ is isomorphic to the pull-back by $\mu$ of the tautological bundle of ${\rm Gr}(k,V)$.

Is it possible to describe 'what vector bundles are tangent bundles' in terms of Grassmannians? And finally: is there a standard translation between these two perspectives on the same subject?

Comment: Basically you want to classify all vector bundles on $M$, then decide whether your bundle is (isomorphic to) the tangent bundle.

Comment: Well, I tried to write the question in a 'fancier' way in order to open more possibilities for the answers. For example, what special properties do tangent bundles have (not in a direct reference to the extra structures they carry, but possibly in relation with them...) among vector bundles in general? In other words, I'm more interested in a 'characterization' than in a 'criterion'. Anyway, what you said would probably be part, even if implicitly, of such an answer.

Comment: Maybe there is a better answer using the synthetic version?  I don't know enough about synthetic differential geometry to answer that question though.

Comment: I think you're mistaken about the Grassmanian : the universal bundle over $Gr(m,V)$ has rank $m$, so the rank of $E$ would be $m$, which is the dimension of $M$, not the rank of $E$. For a compact manifold $M$ of dimension $m$ and a real vector bundle of rank $n$, there is some $k$ and a vector space of dimension $k,V$ with a map $M\to Gr(n,V)$ classifying $E$. Not sure this is true if $M$ is not compact, though

Comment: @MaximeRamzi, you are right. I'll edit the question.

Comment: There are two possible interpretations to $\operatorname{Vect(Diff)}$. Either as a sub of $\operatorname{Diff}$ or pairs $(X,E)$ with $X$ a manifold and $E$ vector bundle on $X$. Which do you mean?

Comment: @Mohan In principle, I was thinking about the category of pairs. However, the question if an arbitrary smooth manifold $N$ admits a (non-trivial) 'vector bundle structure', and in particular if it is isomorphic to the tangent bundle of some smooth manifold $M$, sounds quite interesting too, but probably much more complicated than I initially intended. So, let's assume we're dealing with the category of pairs. I'm not sure if I employed the most adequate terminology for that.

Comment: If you mean pairs, you have an adjoint functor $(X,E)\mapsto X$ and then you have no choices. So question is unclear.

Comment: Yes, of course! I feel that not even in radically distinct models the type of choice you suggested would exist, maybe someone could clarify this point even further. But still, there might be some 'invariants' of vector bundles whose definition would inevitably rely on the base manifold $M$, but whose relations might make a precise meaning for the question 'what vector bundles are tangent bundles', somehow independently of $M$. Thanks for the help on making the question clearer!